# Question about the adjective "looped" [in a children's book called Chicka Chicka Boom Boom]

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

Recently I've been reading a children's book called *Chicka Chicka Boom Boom*.

When the page turns to the page showed as below, I feel puzzled about the adjective **"looped"**.

In this book the lowercase letters are described as kids. When these kids all climbed on the coconut tree, the tree couldn't afford them all and fell. Then all the letters(kids) fell out of the tree and got hurt. Then the letter m is looped.

[image]

I've checked it in online dictionary and it shows that "looped" is originated from the noun "loop" and it seems to have a connection with the aerobatic loop.

And then I heard a song called **"I'm looped"**. And the verse **"Yes I'm looped, high as a Georgia pine"** is kept repeated in the song.
I've checked the meaning of it online and knew that it means **"I'm drunk"**.

So, here is my question:

Does "looped" mean the feeling of being drunk? like getting a bit dizzy and lightheaded? Thus letter m is dizzy in this book after fell from the tree?

Or it just mean the letter m is squashed like two loops that aircrafts make (es. loop the loop) ?

Thanks!

Comment: It's something of a "nonsense ditty", so ***m is looped***  would be completely meaningless to anyone who didn't see the accompanying picture with the letter M written in such a weird way. I don't think there's anything useful here in terms of learning English for non-natives. It looks like something targeted at very young native Anglophone children - intended as a light-hearted way of introducing the concept of ***letters*** in the context of a play school singalong session .

Comment: (In case it's not obvious, I'm quite sure there's no intended allusion to ***looped = intoxicated**!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "there's no intended allusion to looped = intoxicated!"-ok, I see. It seems that I think too much.     " It looks like something targeted at very young native Anglophone children"-Yes, it's a classic picture book for young native speakers. It's like a language play and the words in it seems like nursery rhyme and tongue-twister.   Thanks for your reply. It's very instructive! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, *The book begins with the letter A telling the letter B and B telling the letter C to meet "at the top of the coconut tree." The letters, in alphabetical order, begin to climb the tree.* It's not *directly* aimed at teaching children to read. It's the kind of publication used by play school workers to entertain (and supposedly *teach*) toddlers. In a context where no-one really has any idea whether there's any "educational" value to the exercise anyway). I wouldn't include *any* version of ***loop*** (verb, noun OR adjective) in the top 3000 words worth introducing to toddlers!

Comment: (And no variant of ***stoop*** appears in [the **10,000** "most common"](https://englishgrammarhere.com/vocabulary/10000-most-common-words-in-english-part-5/) English words. It's only there because it rhymes, for the singalong! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looped has a more general meaning than aerobatics. Something that is looped is formed into a curve or circle or part thereof. It is often used to describe things like rope or woolen yarn during the process of knot tying or knitting respectively.

In this case it appears to be describing the way the lowercase letter "m" has been distorted by its fall from the tree.

Looped has other meanings, such as yet another slang term for intoxicated, but they can all be ignored in this context. As for the aerobatic usage, it is the path of the aircraft that is formed into a loop or circle, sometimes emphasised by trailing smoke for display.

As a complete aside, I am dubious about a book that shows distorted letters to confuse children it is trying to teach how to recognise them.

Comment: I am OK with introducing children to the idea that letters come in different styles, but that their essential identity persists. I remember when I was about 6, a poster in our classroom which showed a sad lower case 'g' left behind while fun activities were going on elsewhere (huntin', fishin', playin' etc). The idea was to get the little Cockneys to 'talk proper' and not omit final the final 'g' of such words. The letter was shown in 'fish-hook' style, like in Arial, Helvetica, etc, and not in 'loop-tail' as in Times Roman, or 'two little eggs' as I thought of it. This was very intriguing.

Comment: You're doing sliglhtly odd looking paragraphs, using a   linebreak instead of a paragraph.  The best way to start a normal paragraph is to leave a blank line, and use linebreaks for things like poetry.

Comment: A loop can also be a semicircle of thread, for example [the kind for holding a button](https://mavenpatterns.co.uk/make-button-loop/). The letter 'm' has two shapes like this.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! It's very informative, and I'm inspired by the thought that it might be the way the lowercase letter "m" has been distorted by its fall from the tree. Thanks a lot!